# Unable to pass the through the JSON second time, and turning the flag to false

Tags: json, swift

Here is my code and its output in the console. I am surprised that I am able to parse through the JSON for the first time but not the second time. Could you please advise?

`print("****:", pastPredictionsArray)` is never executed. I think `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` is unable to parse my JSON the second time. Please see the console output.

Snippet:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    print("HTTP Status Code:", httpResponse.statusCode)
    if let data = data, let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
           print("Response JSON:", jsonObject)
       }
    
}
guard let data = data else {
            print("No data received")
            return
        }
do {
    if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
       let pastPredictionsArray = jsonResponse["past_predictions"] as? [[[String: Any]]] {
        var allDecodedPredictions: [Prediction] = []
        print("****:", pastPredictionsArray)
        for predictionsArray in pastPredictionsArray {
            for predictionData in predictionsArray {
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: predictionData, options: [])
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Prediction.self, from: jsonData)
                    allDecodedPredictions.append(decodedData)
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding prediction:", error)
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.decodedPredictions = allDecodedPredictions
            self.isLoading = false
        }
    }
```

Console Output:

```
HTTP Status Code: 200
Response JSON: ["past_predictions": <__NSArrayI 0x600002b401c0>(
<__NSArrayI 0x600002519200>(
"Sample_Request_String",
{"Status": "Pass", "Payload": {dictionaries}], "UserId": "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY", "Id": "xyz"}},
2023-08-31 12:49:28
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x6000025181e0>(
"Sample_Request_String",
{"Status": "Pass", "Payload": {dictionaries}], "UserId": "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY", "Id": "xyz"}},
2023-08-31 12:49:13
)

)
]
```

I am trying to parse through each dictionary and display the result on the UI.

Comment: @Larme I mean, `print("****:", pastPredictionsArray)` isn't executing. Even though I am parsing it again in `JSONSerialization`

Comment: You have `if let a = b as? c, d = e as? f... {} else { "no else" }`, start by doing `if let a = b { if let a2 = b as? c { if let d = e { if d as? f {} else { print("e is not of type f") }} else { print("e is nil") } } else { print("b is not of type c" } } else { print("b is ni") }` and you should si where it fails... I think I got the issue by reading your response, but debugging is important, so whenever a `if` fails, check or add an `else`, and if multiple `if` (here you have to `if let`), check which one fails to advance.

Comment: I recommend to use `Codable`, it can tell you quite precisely what's wrong.

Comment: Could you also print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`, not only `jsonObject` as it can be harder to read... But I guess that `as? [[[String: Any]]]` is failing, and it should be `[[Any]]`, or maybe `[[String]]`, it's hard to tell exactly since you cut some info in the response.

Comment: @Larme Thank you. Both `[[Any]]` and `[[String]]` are setting `self.isLoading = false` now. My UI preview and Xcode are crashing. Thank you. I will investigate and reply back now. btw, `print("String->",String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` is providing console output as, `String-> Optional("{\"past_predictions\":[[\"\\\"Sample_Request_String\\\"\",\"{\\\"Status\\\": \\\"Pass\\\", \\\"Payload\\\": {\\\dictionaries_with_lots_of_\\\},\"2023-08-31 12:49:13\"]]}\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larme, I am could solve my issues. This following code is working.

```
 let pastPredictionsArray = jsonResponse["past_predictions"] as? [[String]] {
                    var allDecodedPredictions: [Prediction] = []
                    print("****:", pastPredictionsArray)
                    for predictionsArray in pastPredictionsArray {
                        for predictionData in predictionsArray {
                            do {
                                print("****:", predictionData)
                                
                                // Assuming predictionData is a JSON-formatted string
                                if let jsonData = predictionData.data(using: .utf8) {
                                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Prediction.self, from: jsonData)
                                    allDecodedPredictions.append(decodedData)
                                } else {
                                    print("Could not convert to Data")
                                }
                                
                            } catch {
                                print("Error decoding prediction:", error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```